# Is Business Validation in a Value Object acceptable?

Tags: design-patterns, enterprise, paradigms

We have a multi-tenant application which, for better or worse, handles the the distinction between different customers with lots of if-then-else statements all over the place. I have a particularly simple validation that needs to be performed on data entry similar to the following scenario:

Let's say we have an object called `Thermometer` with a property called `temperature`. When the user enters a number, we need to round it to the nearest 3rd decimal. So, if they enter "65.65432", we need to store "65.654". But wait, there's more. Client Bob likes detail and doesn't want the number rounded. Client Sarah is the one that requested the rounding.

How to do this is simple enough, but *where* to do this is my question. I would like to do this directly on the value object, `Thermometer`, since it's quick and simple and just *seems* right. However, since only one client requested it, this falls into the realm of "business logic/validation." Is it still acceptable to put this on the value object, or should I suck it up and build this in the presentation layer? Doing that would require wrapping the accessors in a proxy method in the managed bean that handles the UI. Which option has the better pay-off?

**More Details**
For anyone who is interested, this is a J2EE application with JSF. We do normally have the ability to use `<f:numberConverter>`, but in this case we are also using `<a4j:support event="onkeyup" ajaxSingle="true" />` which seems to break numberConverter. So we have to do the rounding manually.

Comment: I vote for performing the validation in the UI as much as possible

Comment: Well, how do you differentiate between clients now?  User session?  Configuration file?  I'd use those, but I don't know if you are able to.

Comment: The question is not how to differentiate between clients. That's trivial because we do it all the time. For the purpose of this discussion, assume we have a function `isUserSarah()`. In the real world issue I'm trying to solve, I can get the client from a nested property.

Comment: Note: I didn't add the JSF tag to this question because it is not specific to JSF, nor does the use of JSF affect the solution. The "More Details" was simply to rule out the "let your presentation framework handle it" answer, and it actually reinforces that JSF is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 1):

Surely you want to model the different requirements in different classes that could be plugged-in dependent on the client. Something like a strategy. That way you can unit test each independently and keep coupling nice and low.